# Proving uniform bounded derivatives from uniformly bounded derivatives of the image of a differential operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function. Let

$$g(x)=\frac{d^2 f}{dx^2}(x)+f(x).$$

Suppose that, for each integer $l\geq 0$, there exists $C_l>0$ such that

$$\frac{d^l g}{dx^l}(x)\leq C_l$$

for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Does it follow that $f$ is also uniformly bounded and has uniformly bounded derivative of every order? That is, for every $k\geq 0$, does there exist $B_k>0$ such that

$$\frac{d^k f}{dx^k}(x)\leq B_k$$

for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,
$$
f''+f=g
$$
is just a nonhomogeneous linear differential equation with general solution
$$
f(x)=(A+\int_0^x g(t)\cos t\,dt)\sin x+(B-\int_0^x g(t) \sin t\,dt)\cos x.
$$
If $g(t)=\cos t$ (which is clearly bounded together with all its derivatives), then the unbounded function
$$
f(x)=\sin x\int_0^x \cos^2 t\,dt-\cos x\int_0^x \cos t\sin t\,dt=\frac x 2\sin x
$$
is a solution of the differential equation.

Comment: I think $f(x)$ in your case should evaluate to $\frac{1}{2}x\sin(x)$ (which is unbounded nevertheless).

Comment: You are absolutely right. That was the one step for which I did not use a CAS ...